relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `timing_' can not be used when making a shared object
When I try to execute my project on a machine without arpack++, I encounter the error 'libarpack.so.2: cannot open shared object file.' I attempted to rebuild the project after uninstalling arpack++, and I placed libarpack.a in the following path: /home/libs.
error:  /home/libs/libarpack.a(dsaupd.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `timing_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

What command are you using to build your project? Are you trying to static-link arpack but dynamic link everything else?
